# Meta Query if Values Don't Exist

Tags: wp-query, loop, meta-query

I'm struggling to get the parameters correct for a meta query for posts (surveys, actually) which have a start and end date (time string). I need to query posts: which have an end date later than now OR don't have an end date AND which have a start date before now OR don't have a start date. My query looks like this but is failing to return my post which has no start or end date.

```
'meta_query'        => [
    'relation'      => 'AND',
    [
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        [
            'key'       => 'start_date',
            'value'     => time(),
            'compare'   => '<='
        ],[
            'key'       => 'start_date',
            'value'     => '',
            'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ]
    ],[
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        [
            'key'       => 'end_date',
            'value'     => time(),
            'compare'   => '>='
        ],[
            'key'       => 'end_date',
            'value'     => '',
            'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ]
    ]
]
```

Question: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would note that such a query will be *very* slow/expensive, and will not scale as traffic increases. Always query for what you want, not what you don't want

Comment: Okay, noted, @TomJNowell. Can you suggest a better approach? I can't think of a more efficient approach for what I need to achieve, i.e.: checking the date range IF it exists. Thanks.

Comment: You could query all "survey" posts, then use a PHP loop to check each for your conditions.